# Duplicar una tupla cambiando un campo

Tags: sql, oracle

Muy buenas. Tengo una tabla llamada ALBARAN_VENTAS en la cual debo hacer una réplica de una tupla tal y como me lo pide el siguiente ejercicio:

> REPLICAR_ALBARAN. Generará la replicación de un albarán de ventas
>   (incluidas las líneas). El albarán a replicar será el primero
>   encontrado ordenando por empresa, organización comercial,
>   numero_serie, numero albarán y ejercicio de forma descendente. Este
>   nuevo albarán tendrá los mismos datos que el albarán replicado, salvo
>   el número del albarán. Este número será el máximo + 1 que exista en la
>   tabla de albaranes (ALBARAN_VENTAS_FORMACION) para el número de serie
>   del albarán que estamos replicando.

Empresa, organizacion_comercial, numero_serie, numero_albaran y ejercicio son campos de dicha tabla y entre todas forman la PK.

Hasta ahora he desarrollado:

PARA ENCONTRAR EL REGISTRO:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM ALBARAN_VENTAS_FORMACION
WHERE NUMERO_ALBARAN IN(
    SELECT * 
    FROM (
        SELECT NUMERO_ALBARAN, EMPRESA, ORGANIZACION_COMERCIAL, NUMERO_SERIE, NUMERO_ALBARAN, EJERCICIO
        FROM ALBARAN_VENTAS_FORMACION
        ORDER BY EMPRESA DESC, ORGANIZACION_COMERCIAL DESC, NUMERO_SERIE DESC, NUMERO_ALBARAN DESC, EJERCICIO DESC)
    WHERE ROWNUM =1)
```

PARA ENCONTRAR EL REGISTRO CON EL NUMERO MÁS ALTO AL QUE SUMAR +1

```sql
SELECT NUMERO_ALBARAN
FROM (
    SELECT NUMERO_ALBARAN
    FROM ALBARAN_VENTAS_FORMACION
    ORDER BY NUMERO_ALBARAN DESC)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

No sé como juntarlos para hacer un INSERT, ya que lo he intentado y me da error, a pesar de que las querys funcionan perfectamente por separado. Podríais echarme una mano? Muchas gracias :)

Comment: Tiene que ser en una sola consulta? sabes hacer group by?

Comment: Sí, claro, pero en este caso no sé si me hará falta un group by, ya que la query me devuelve un único resultado

Comment: En realidad para evitar usar rownum, un group by, con la funcion max te devuelve el maximo valor de una columna. con eso evitarias recorrer toda la tabla y dejarla ordenada. Ademas, esa query la podrias insertar en tu insert sin problemas.

Comment: No había pensado en ello! Muchísimas gracias, voy a intentarlo como dices :)

Comment: ok. intenta con eso, y vuelve si tienes un problema con esa consulta